# What is wrong with my object(regarding knockoutjs mapping plugin)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm pulling my hair out with this.  I'm not sure what is going on.  I've read all the tutorials on mapping but I'm obviously missing something.

```
{
        "address": "110",
        "city": "Durham",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Keep",
        "persistent": true,
        "salesRep": "Me",
        "state": "NC",
        "user": {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Test",
            "password": "test",
            "persistent": true
        }
    }
```

I've tried

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
```

and

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
```

In my old code I ended up doing this.

```
    viewModel.customers(data);
```

But my JSON looked different.  It didn't have a nested object and it also had brackets on the beginning and end making it an array.  It seems this would be pretty basic.  I'm not getting any errors at all.  Thanks for the help.

**EDIT**

http://jsfiddle.net/gjemN/

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to repro the problem?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is not happening that you think should be happening?

Comment: Ok guys added the jsfiddle.  @BryanRoss:  I'm just trying to get the mapping done from a JSON string.  At this point it is not working.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sample you are dealing with a JavaScript object and not JSON (string representation of it).

So, you would want to call ko.mapping.fromJS.  If you are getting back an array of customers, then you could do:

`ko.mapping.fromJS(data2, null, viewModel.customers)`

Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/BQe2z/

Comment: I'll go with this.  I feel like a complete idiot.  My JSON was being created in Java.  Stupidly enough, I wasn't mapping a Java List to a Json array, I was mapping an object.  So what I had was just an object and not an array.  That's why it wouldn't work.  Derp.  Lol.

Comment: Hi @RP, what does the "null" paramter for?